# unity ui and collider2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collider

this is a pretty long code for a simple function but i can't seem to know how i can shorten it. any advice?

this is a simple script that i created for a beginner project and i placed the script inside the player object with both rigidbody2d and boxcollider2d and yeah it works and all, it toggles both the button gameobjects which is what i was going for in a sense but i wanted it to use only one button. if you can help with this as well i would appreciate it.

```
//different button objects
public GameObject smithbutton;
public GameObject innbutton;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
//debugs which collider player is in
    if (col.gameObject.name == "Blacksmith")
    {
        Debug.Log("This is the Blacksmith");
    }
    if (col.gameObject.name == "Inn")
    {
        Debug.Log("This is the Inn");
    }
}

private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D col)
{
//once playerobject stays, button will toggle till player leaves
    if (col.gameObject.name == "Blacksmith")
    {
        Debug.Log("still on the Blacksmith's door");
        smithbutton.SetActive(true);
    }
    if (col.gameObject.name == "Inn")
    {
        Debug.Log("still on the Inn's door");
        innbutton.SetActive(true);
    }
}

private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D col)
{
//once playerobject exits, button will toggle and disappear
    if (col.gameObject.name == "Blacksmith")
    {
        smithbutton.SetActive(false);
    }
    if (col.gameObject.name == "Inn")
    {
        innbutton.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no much you could do, as the function is quite simple. You could make it better, and still reduce some of the lines. Using tag instead of name will be future proof if you create more Inns or more blacksmiths. Using the collider call a method will let you extend the functionality with ease. I will usually add each of this checks to the Inn and Blacksmiths myself, and they will be looking for the player.

```
//different button objects
[SerializeField] private GameObject smithbutton;
[SerializeField] private GameObject innbutton;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
//debugs which collider player is in
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Blacksmith")
    {
        ButtonActivationToggle(smithbutton, col);
    }
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Inn")
    {
        ButtonActivationToggle(innbutton, col);
    }
}

private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D col)
{
//once playerobject exits, button will toggle and disappear
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Blacksmith")
    {
        ButtonActivationToggle(smithbutton, col);
    }
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Inn")
    {
        ButtonActivationToggle(innbutton, col);
    }
}

public void ButtonActivationToggle(GameObject button, Collider2D collider)
{
    bool tmp = false;
    tmp = button.activeInHierarchy ? false : true;
    button.SetActive(tmp);
    if (button.activeInHierarchy)
    {
        Debug.Log("This is the " + gameObject.collider.tag)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont need the OnTriggerStay, you can do that in OnTriggerEnter and get rid of the Stay function.

```
public Button mybtn;
bool isBlacksmith; // keep track of where you are (you can later make it an enum if there are more than 2 places and check that)

void Start()
{
    //when the button is clicked buttonFunction will be called
    mybtn.onClick.AddListener(buttonFunction);
}
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.name == "Blacksmith")
    {
        Debug.Log("Entered Blacksmith's door");
        mybtn.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        isBlacksmith = true;
    }
    if (col.gameObject.name == "Inn")
    {
        Debug.Log("Entered Inn's door");
        mybtn.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        isBlacksmith = false;
    }
}

private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D col)
{
    //once playerobject exits, button will toggle and disappear
    if (col.gameObject.name == "Blacksmith" || col.gameObject.name == "Inn")
    {
        smithbutton.SetActive(false);
    }
}

public void buttonFunction()
{
    if (isBlacksmith)
        Debug.Log("In Blacksmith");
    else
        Debug.Log("In Inn");

}
```